# IE javascript setting style.left not working

Tags: javascript, cross-browser

Hey,
I'm struggling setting a style attribute to a div that's created via javascript. 
The flow is:

1. The script loads
2. It creates a `<div id="test">`
3. It sets attribute `style="top: 20px; left: 10px; margin: 0px; position: absolute;"`

Everything works fine with all other browsers but when it comes to IE things just don't work.
How can I set those style attributes in IE ? So far with this code:

```
var div = document.getElementById('test');
div.style.left     = "10px";
div.style.top      = "20px";
div.style.margin   = "0px";
div.style.position = "absolute !important";
```

I was able to set top, margin and position. Style.left is out of the question.

What's the best approach when dealing with style attributes in all browsers ?

@IE not working version: 7,8. (haven't tried it under 6 and 9)

Comment: Try setting the `position:absolute` first before you set the `left`, `top`, etc properties.

Comment: There is no need for the important.

Comment: I tried setting position to be the first thing but still it doesn't work. Can all these attributes be a string and set them as div.setAttribute('style',myStyleString); ?

Comment: Unrelated, but consider a library: [`$('#test').css({left: 100, top: 50, margin: 0, position: 'absolute'});`](http://jsfiddle.net/hLHUs/)

Comment: Yeah.. That would have worked if I could use jquery but in this case it has to be plain javascript.

Comment: IE 7/8 .. Haven't tried it with 6 or 9.

Comment: @tftd Hm, the code looks OK. Could you provide a live demo of the issue?

Comment: At this moment I can't put it online. It seems to me that it's a variable type of problem. If we have div.style.left = myIntegerVariable+"px"; should that work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After a couple of hours debugging the code I finally managed to get it right. 
The problem was I had a variable that returned numeric. That variable was the base of some calculation and it was used when setting div.style.left. So the variable sometimes returned NaN which caused the pain. :)
Thanks to everybody for the effort and the time spent trying to help! :)

Comment: had same problem here. i use parseInt instead of Number function to force it to numeric

Comment: best solution is to use element.style.cssText if you can replace the styles

Answer (score 2):

> What's the best approach when dealing
>   with style attributes in all browsers?

Setting just `div.className` and moving all CSS to CSS file.

Comment: Can't happen. This div is supposed to move when you scroll the page. :)

Comment: What do you mean "fixed" @epascarello ? As like setting a fixed position?

Comment: @tftd: you can use css `position: fixed` so that it stays in the same position on your screen whilst scrolling.  JavaScript isn't necessary.

Answer (score 2):

```
div.style.cssText="top: 20px; left: 10px; margin: 0px; position: absolute;"
```

remember that the div'es position is relative to its parent- some old IE's need the parent element position set to relative or absolute, depending on the doctype.

Comment: setting the style with .style = '...'; works in Waterfox (Firefox) but NOT in IE and Chrome :(. But this hint of using .style.cssText = '...'; does the trick. Superb!!!

Answer (score 2):

```
function MuoveOnClickPosition(YourDIVObject) {

//numeric variables.
tempX = event.clientX;
tempY = event.clientY;

// String variables
var X, Y ;
X = tempX + 'px'; 
Y = tempY + 'px'; 

document.getElementById(YourDIVObject).style.left = X;
document.getElementById(YourDIVObject).style.top = Y;
}
```

//Should work !.. sometimes IE needs 'XXXpx' in string format. It depend on DOC Type.`

Comment: For what it's worth, this very answer (needing the "px") just solved a HUGE problem for me that I was having with a 3rd party library.  It had a whole bunch of Javascript that put elements in weird positions in the page in recent IE versions (and all other browsers) but IE5 quirks mode worked a treat.  I guess old IE6 and under works with or without px, but newer versions complain without the px.  Anyway, long way of saying thanks for the answer! :P

Answer (score 1):

The !important is killing the position absolute. Does not even work in Firefox. Tested on [JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/aroxo3/edit)

Comment: It works just fine in Firefox. I've tested it with a couple of versions under Windows and Linux. Also works under Safari, Opera, Chrome. Anyway never mind it. I've removed it and still it's not working under IE :)